# How to add another level in Guess game using java that generates every attempt a new random number

Tags: java

Hello everyone I'm still new in java but I was trying to do this guess game that has 2 levels first one in a normal guess game the second level is that the user has 5 attempts to guess the number but each time he/she fails it generates a new random number but I can't link the 2 levels together when I pass the first level it gets me to the second but with the conditions of the first and doesn't generate a random number each attempt I hope you guys have the knowledge to let me know what kind of mistakes I made

```
package guessing_game;
import java.util.Random;


public class Game {
    Random random = new Random();
    private boolean gameOver;
    private int secretNumber;
    private int numberOfGuess;
    public Game(int range) {
  gameOver = false;
  secretNumber = random.nextInt(10);
  numberOfGuess = 0;
}
    public boolean isGameOver() {
  return gameOver;
}

public boolean guess(int n) {
  if (gameOver) {
    System.out.println("The game is over. " 
        + "You can not guess again.");
  } else if (n == secretNumber) {
    System.out.println("You guessed right!"
            +"let's go to next level.");
    gameOver = false;
  } else {
    if (n < secretNumber) {
        System.out.println("Your guess is too low.");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Your guess is too high.");
    }
    numberOfGuess++;
    if (numberOfGuess == 5) {
      System.out.println("You have used up all of your guesses.");
      gameOver = true;
    }
    
  }
  return gameOver;
}
public void guess2(int n){
if (gameOver) {
    System.out.println("The game is over. " 
        + "You can not guess again.");
  } else if (n == secretNumber) {
    System.out.println("You guessed right!");
    gameOver = true;
  } else {
    if (n < secretNumber) {
        System.out.println("Your guess is not right.");
        secretNumber=random.nextInt(10);
    } else {
        System.out.println("Your guess is not right.");
        secretNumber=random.nextInt(10);
    }
    numberOfGuess++;
    if (numberOfGuess == 5) {
      System.out.println("You have used up all of your guesses.");
      gameOver = true;
    }
  }





}
}

package guessing_game;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Guessing_game {

    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
     Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
     Game theGame = new Game(10);
     while(theGame.isGameOver() == false){
        System.out.println("Guess a number between 0 and 10:");
        int n = input.nextInt();
        theGame.guess(n);
        if(theGame.guess(n)==false)
            theGame.guess2(n);
    }
    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Break the problem down into the steps you described.

You have two levels for guessing random a number.

- First level: infinite guesses of a fixed random number
- Second level: max 5 guesses of a random number that changes with each guess

Something like

```
public class Game {
    public boolean play() {
        Random random = new Random();
        int level = 1;
        int secretNumber = random.nextInt(10); // random number for all of level 1
        // infinite guesses for level 1
        do {
            int guess = ... // get user input from keyboard
            if (guess == secretNumber) {
                level++;
            }
        } while (level == 1);
        // level 2, only five guesses
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            // level 2, random number changes at each failed guess
            secretNumber = random.nextInt(10);
            int guess = ... // get user input from keyboard
            if (guess == secretNumber) {
                return true; // they won the game
            }
        }
        return false; // they lost
    }
}
```